# How can I get the filesystem sector size from unix/linux/osx and windows?

Tags: c, windows, linux, macos, unix

I want to be able to determine at runtime what the sector size is for a give filesystem. C code is acceptable. for example I format my Data partitions with a 32k sector size that have lots of large video files. I want to be able to get this value at runtime.

Comment: yes sector size would be a more correct term

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want [statvfs](http://linux.die.net/man/2/statvfs) (if by pagesize you mean sector size?) which from what I remember works linux and OSX. I think you need to use the f_bsize field but I unfortunately do not have a linux box to test against atm.

For windows you want the [GetDiskFreeSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364935%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: `statvfs()` is indeed one way to do it on Linux (it's a POSIX function).  `statfs()` is an alternative on Linux, and as a BSD-derived function it's the one that's available on OSX.  In both cases the `f_bsize` field of the returned structure is the one you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int page_size = getpagesize();
        printf("The page size is %d\n", page_size);
        exit(0);
}
```

Comment: getpagesize() returns the page size for memory, not the filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, call the  [GetSystemInfo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724381(VS.85).aspx) function

```
void WINAPI GetSystemInfo(
  __out  LPSYSTEM_INFO lpSystemInfo
);
```

Then access the dwPageSize value in the returned [SYSTEM_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724958(VS.85).aspx) structure.  This size is guaranteed to give file system page aligment.  For example, use this size for reading and writing files in unbuffered mode.

If you need the volumen sector size, simply call [GetDiskFreeSpace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364935(VS.85).aspx) function then read the lpBytesPerSector value.