# Is it guaranteed that the beginning of a file is aligned with Pagesize of file system?

Tags: filesystems, page-size

It seems we can do nothing to aid the file system alignment if even this doesn't hold.

Is it true?

Comment: Disks are read by blocks (usually 512 or more recently 4096 bytes), not by pages.

Comment: @jiliagre vast majority of filesystems operates with pages or clusters. The page can be equal (but not smaller) than the hardware block, but usually it's larger.

Comment: Pages are Pagesize are usually referring to Operating System virtual memory allocation units. This doesn't relate that much to how a file system is laying out its files. @new_perl: Can you clarify what you are asking here and what problem you are trying to solve ?

Comment: @jlliagre and who told you that the filesystem must not use the term "page"? Just in case, our SolFS operates with pages, not clusters, and so do DBMS.

Comment: I never wrote a file system "must not" use the page metaphor, just that "pages" and "pagesize" are usually associated with virtual memory. I'm simply not familiar with pagesize associated with file systems and it seems I'm not the only one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045466/how-can-i-get-the-filesystem-page-size-from-unix-linux-osx-and-windows

Comment: @new_perl: Can you clarify what you are asking here and what problem you are trying to solve ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that by pagesize you mean the file system logical allocation unit (typically 4K or 8K clusters), you cannot assume a file will start at a boundary with every file system.

Many FS based on FFS (SunOS/SVR4 and HP-UX UFS, BSD UFS1 & UFS2, LFS) implements fragments in order to save space when a lot of small files are created. Note that while ext2/3 is based on FFS, it doesn't support fragments.

Other common (or less common) FS that implement block sub-allocation are Netware FS, ReiserFS, Reiser4, IBM JFS2, Sun SAM/QFS and VMWare VMFS.

Modern file systems like btrfs and zfs also support block sub allocation.

With all these file systems, a small file might start at a non null offset from an allocation unit boundary.

In any case, large files, i.e. files larger than the allocation unit will likely start at a boundary on almost all if not all file systems.

Comment: How do you optimize the disk IO for those FS that **you cannot assume a file will start at a boundary** then? Is there a way to verify that **files larger than the allocation unit will likely start at a boundary on almost all if not all file systems** instead of referring to the specs, say , is there a way to print out the offset?

Comment: For files smaller that the allocation unit, there is nothing to optimize. The whole file is read in a single operation

Comment: Is there a way to verify if it's true for large files?

Comment: I'm not trying to solve any particular problem, just curious.

Comment: Well then my answer would be whether a file starts at a cluster boundary or not doesn't really matter in term of performance. There are plenty of things that have a much larger performance impact in a file system implementation that this particular detail.